# Why was a 2-1B droid attending the war meeting where Mon Mothma addresses the Rebel forces?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Return of the Jedi*, when the High Command briefs Rebel commanders aboard the ship Home One, we can see a 2-1B droid sitting among them. I understand the presence of other droids like R2-D2 and C-3PO that were directly involved in the tactical and strategic war scenario, but is there a particular reason for the presence of a surgical droid in the war room?

[image: Still of The Return of the Jedi]

It is worth mentioning that aside from the 2-1B, at the beginning of the scene, another medical droid (a FX-7 medical assistant droid) can bee seen standing next to two astromechs.

[image]

Comment: How many prop droids did you expect them to make? :)

Comment: If you're heading into a shooting situation, it's a good idea to keep the ship's doctor advised so they can prepare for casualties, set up triage, pre-stock supplies, etc. etc.  And they might have feedback that would impact the plan ("we're all out of Bothan blood, if you send them in first, many of them will die.")

Comment: The same reason the Holo-doctor is part of the command structure of Voyager - it's all they got.  Someone has to tend to the wounded, and that someone has to know what's going on.

Comment: @DavidW - Well, that was a very good one because they kept puppeting his head and blinking his torso all along the scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments if you are heading into a battle situation you would want your medical teams fully briefed and prepared to accept casualties so its perfectly logical they would be at the briefing.

In the actual battle above Endor we do actually see the medical frigate engaged as part of the battle.

In this clip right at the start, you can see the engines of the medical frigate in the centre left of screen , then at two minutes and fifty seconds Wedge Antillies clearly states "They're heading for the medical frigate" as he pursues some Tie Fighters. Three Tie fighters fly towards the ship and an X wing and the Millennium Falcon follow them, chasing them off. The Falcon then flies directly under the medical frigate.

So we can see that the medical ship was committed to the battle.

Additional information on this particular spacecraft can be found on the Starwars.com website

https://www.starwars.com/databank/nebulon-b-frigate

where it is listed as a Nebulon-B Medical Frigate and armed with turbo lasers and tractor beams. They were assigned to escort and protect rebel convoys. In the all out attack on the second Death Star this ship was also committed to the battle. So we see it is essential for medical droids who would have been crewing this ship to be at the briefing.